# What does ` $($@.c) ` mean in a Makefile when it appears in the prerequisites of a rule?

Tags: c, makefile

```
TARGETS = a b c d
$(TARGETS) : $($@.c)  
    $(CC)  -c $@.c
    $(CC) $@.o -o ../bin/$@
    rm -f $@.o
```

I know how it works, this rule iterates over the variable TARGETS to compile the `.c` file with filename identical to its corresponding part in TARGETS. But I was not capable of finding the detail of this grammar in the mannul.

Which part should I refer to to know more about it?

Comment: GNU Make `3.9 Secondary Expansion`

Comment: There is no make variable `@.c`, so `$(@.c)` expands to nothing (unless you've set that variable yourself).  Either you have a typo in your question and the prerequisite was really `$@.c` or `$(@).c`, or the makefile is wrong (or there is an assignment of `@.c` that you didn't show us).

Comment: Agree with Mad. Try print the prerequisites in the recipe: `echo "$^"`. Chances are it turns up blank.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is blank. But how does it work? Are there some underlying rules that will automatically add a .c file when calling gcc?

Comment: @Scriabin In that case the rule is broken. It clearly depends on a .c-file, but since the prerequisites (`$^`) are empty make will not rebuild the target should the .c-file change.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` only has a value within the recipe, so the obvious:

```
$(TARGETS) : $@.c
     ...
```

doesn't work, because when the rule is read, `$@` has no value. It's explicitly called out in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

However, if you enable secondary expansion, which applies to rules after the special target

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
```

then `$($@.c)` is expanded to `$@.c` when the rule is first read, and when the rule is used, `$@` will have a value (of the target being built) thanks to secondary expansion. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion

Incidentally, I'm not sure why the rule is so complicated. I don't see why it needs to build the .o file only to delete it later, when C compilers can build a binary from source files without generating an intermediate .o file.

```
$(TARGETS) : $($@.c)
    $(CC) $@.c -o ../bin/$@
```

And the rule is faulty anyway, because the target of the rule is not generated by the recipe: the target is for example "a", but the file generated is "../bin/a".

Comment: There isn't a `.SECONDEXPANSION` in the makefile.
To my knowledge, during the first expansion, as `$@.c` is not a variable name, if we try to expand it, it will evaluate to empty string. Which part of my understanding is problematic?

Comment: *C compilers can build a binary from source files without generating an intermediate .o file* - And for compilers/tools where that's not supported, there is special target `.INTERMEDIATE` that has Make remove the files automatically: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html

Comment: @Andreas There were some other libraries to be linked, and I omitted them.

Comment: @Scriabin, in `make`, variable names are single-character when `$` is used without parentheses or braces, so `$@.c` means the expansion of `$@` concatenated with the literal text `.c`.  It is not a reference to a variable named `@.c` -- that would require the form `$(@.c)` or `${@.c}`.

Answer (score 0):

It just evaluates to an empty string and has no effect. Sorry to bother you.

To make this rule work as expected, one should add '.SECONDEXPANSION' before the rule, and write $$@.c in the prerequisite.

During the first expansion, it becomes `$@.c` and during the second expansion, automatic variable $@ is visible and it is expanded.

Comment: Surely that's not the *intended* effect.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, and, very likely, you don't have a make variable named `.c`, this rule is the same as:

```
$(TARGETS) :
    $(CC)  -c $@.c
    $(CC) $@.o -o ../bin/$@
    rm -f $@.o
```

Moreover, the targets (`a b c d`) are not the files produced by the recipe (`../bin/a`...). This is wrong because make has no way to know when the executables are up-to-date (no prerequisites and wrong targets). The executables will always be rebuilt, even if the source files do not change. A much better and simpler solution would be to use a static pattern rule, and also to use the real target files, instead of non-existing files. If you use GNU make and your compiler knows how to compile and link at once:

```
$(TARGETS) := $(addprefix ../bin/,a b c d)

$(TARGETS): ../bin/%: %.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Now the targets are the real executable files produced by the recipe, and they really depend on their respective source file.